Creating 3 Output Bins In Loops And Range
I'm new to Data analytics, and i'm trying to create an output of 3 bins in python. I'll have my code attached below. I my getting an output, but its not in 3 bins. Also the bins are as follows:
Question: The function must iterate over the scores in score_list and bin them into three bins:
Negative (scores of 1-5)
Neutral (scores of 6-8)
Positive (scores of 9-10)
create score_list from customer submitted scores
The function must iterate over 3 bins
The output of the function must be three statements.
# Define a function score_counter

score_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for score_counter in range(1, 11):
    if score_counter <= (5):
        print('Negative: ' + str(score_counter))
    elif score_counter == (6):
        print('Neutral: ' + str(score_counter))
    elif score_counter == (7):
        print('Neutral: ' + str(score_counter))
    elif score_counter == (8):
        print('Neutral: ' + str(score_counter))
    else:
        print('Positive: '+ str(score_counter))
    print()
    


There is no binning going on here in the sense of placing items into one of three lists. Python lists are 0 indexed so your range is not doing what you hope.

maybe you should work with your list for ... in score_list:. If you have to use range() then it would be safer to use range(len(score_list)) - and it needs to check score_list[score_counter]

maybe you should create 3 lists - negative = [], neutral = [], positive = [] and use for-loop to append() values to these lists. And later you can get len(negative), len(neutral), len(positive) to count values.

eventually you could create 3 variables negative = 0, neutral = 0, positive = 0 and use for-loop with negative += 1, neutral += 1, positive += 1 to count values directly (without using list)

I think you should create three lists negative = [] neutral  = [] positive = [] and use for-loop to append() values to correct list. And later you can use len() to count every list.
score_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

negative = []
neutral  = []
positive = []

for item in score_list:
    if  1 <= item <= 5:
        negative.append(item)
    elif 6 <= item <= 8:
        neutral.append(item)
    elif 9 <= item <= 10: 
        positive.append(item)

print(negative, neutral, positive)
print(len(negative), len(neutral), len(positive))

Result:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [6, 7, 8] [9, 10]
5 3 2

You can also reduce if/elif/else
for item in score_list:
    if  item <= 5:
        negative.append(item)
    elif item <= 8:
        neutral.append(item)
    else:
        positive.append(item)

